# Bootstrap nav item not showing on mobile device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on something small using bootstrap. Here I have a nav bar. For the nav-item "Login" and "Logout" I have set it to stay on the right hand side using `justify-content-end`. On large screen devices it's how I want it to be. But when I open it using a mobile device, the navbar collapses like its meant to, but the item with `justify-content-end` doesn't show up.

Any ideas?
Thank you

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jatitree</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>BuyCars">Buy Goods</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>SellGoods">Sell Goods</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"</li>
        <?php
          if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
            echo '<a class="nav-link" href="'.base_url().'/Login">Login</a>';
            else echo '<a class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>';
        ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: on large device]

[image: on small device/ mobile]

Comment: what if you put the last <li> (login/logout) right below the others <a>, below Sell Goods. and then add float right to login/logout <li>? what happens? removing the <li>, using just <a> of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML is not structured correctly (a should be inside li, and li is missing a closing bracket). But, the issue is you've named 2 elements with the same `id` which won't work. Just use a classname (ie: navbar-alt) to toggle both `collapse` navbars and target this class in `data-target`.

https://www.codeply.com/go/BaZHtvCoAR

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jatitree</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-alt" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-alt" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="&lt;?php echo base_url();?&gt;">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="&lt;?php echo base_url();?&gt;BuyCars">Buy Goods</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="&lt;?php echo base_url();?&gt;SellGoods">Sell Goods</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end navbar-alt">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item nav-link">
                Logout
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```